# Create dashed line in ListView Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

How can I create a dashed line to use as a separator for my list view?

Example:

[image]

Comment: take a look at what Skia gives: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/paths/dots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in custom renderer of listview.

**MyListViewRenderer.cs:**

```
public class MyListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
{
    Context ctx;
    public MyListViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        ctx = context;
    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
            //var listView = Control as Android.Widget.ListView;
            Drawable drawable = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.DashedLines);               

            Control.DividerHeight = 20;
            Control.Divider = drawable;
            Control.SetLayerType(LayerType.Software,null);
        }
    }
}
```

**Xaml:**

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <local:MyListView SeparatorVisibility="None">
        <local:MyListView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                <x:String>mono</x:String>
                <x:String>monodroid</x:String>
                <x:String>monotouch</x:String>
                <x:String>monorail</x:String>
                <x:String>monodevelop</x:String>
                <x:String>monotone</x:String>
               <x:String>monopoly</x:String>
                <x:String>monomodal</x:String>
                <x:String>mononucleosis</x:String>
            </x:Array>
        </local:MyListView.ItemsSource>
    </local:MyListView>
```

**Result:**

[image]

I have uploaded the project on GitHub, you could download from ListViewDashedLinesDemo folder for reference.
https://github.com/WendyZang/Test.git

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve through renderer like below,

```cs
// PCL
public class BoxViewExt : BoxView
{

}

// Android
public class BoxViewExtRenderer : BoxRenderer
{
    public BoxViewExtRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.OnDraw(canvas);

        var paint = new Paint { StrokeWidth = 2, AntiAlias = true };
        paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);
        paint.SetPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new[] { 6 * this.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density, 2 * this.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density }, 0));

        var p = new Path();
        p.LineTo(canvas.Width, 0);
        canvas.DrawPath(p, paint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do it with SaskiSharp and a small custom view.
This solution does not requires custom renderers.

1. Install the following nuget packages to your Xamarin Forms project

   ```
   SkiaSharp
   SkiaSharp.Views.Forms
   ```
2. Create a ContentView

   ```
   public class DashedLineView : ContentView
   {
       public Color LineColor
       {
          get; set;
       } = Color.Black;

       public float DashSize
       {
          get; set;
       } = 20;

       public float WhiteSize
       {
          get; set;
       } = 20;

       public float Phase
       {
          get; set;
       } = 0;

       public DashedLineView()
       {
          Content = new SKCanvasView();
          ((SKCanvasView)Content).PaintSurface += Canvas_PaintSurface;
       }

       private void Canvas_PaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
       {
          SKImageInfo info = args.Info;
          SKSurface surface = args.Surface;
          SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

          canvas.Clear();

          SKPaint paint = new SKPaint
          {
             Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
             Color = LineColor.ToSKColor(),
             StrokeWidth = HeightRequest > 0 ? (float)HeightRequest : (float)WidthRequest,
             StrokeCap = SKStrokeCap.Butt,
             PathEffect = SKPathEffect.CreateDash(new float[] { DashSize, WhiteSize }, Phase)
          };

          SKPath path = new SKPath();
          if (HeightRequest > 0)
          {
             // Horizontal
             path.MoveTo(0, 0);
             path.LineTo(info.Width, 0);
          }
          else
          {
             // Vertikal
             path.MoveTo(0, 0);
             path.LineTo(0, info.Height);
          }

          canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
       }
    }
   ```
3. Use it in XAML

   ```
   <views:DashedLineView
           VerticalOptions="Center"
           HorizontalOptions="Fill"
           LineColor="#f60"
           HeightRequest="10"
           DashSize="30"
           WhiteSize="50" />
   ```

Comment: But on make it vertical it will not cover in the whole layout only two dashes will appear
for that Change in Xaml 

<views:DashedLineView
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        LineColor="Gray"
        WidthRequest="4"
        DashSize="30"
        WhiteSize="50" />

Answer (score 0):

1. 

```
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags(new string[] { "Brush_Experimental", "Shapes_Experimental" });
```

2. 

```
<Line Grid.Row="0"
      Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
      X2="10"
      Stroke="Red"
      StrokeThickness="0.8" 
      StrokeDashArray="1,8"
      Aspect="UniformToFill"
      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
      VerticalOptions="End"/>
```